# How do I efficiently return kernel malloc data back to cpu

Tags: c++, cuda, gpgpu

Lets say I `malloc` some struct inside a kernel where I performed some calculation upon. I then want to return these variable, however they were not sent in as pointers when I initialized the kernel,So If I want to return these value. How would I go about doing so? Sample codes below.

I am only asking this as a general question not to solve the code below. I have other issues where I run into this and I don't know what's the best way to go about it. I understand that you can just throw in a pointer and copy the results onto it. However if the size of the result isn't predetermined it would be very hard to do so efficiently. So I am asking if there is a better way.

```
__global__ void addKernel()
{
    int* c = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * 32);
#pragma unroll
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++){
        c[i] += 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Pointers allocated using device side allocation (`new`, `malloc`, or `cudaMalloc`) cannot be used by host side API calls. So the only way to transfer data stored in memory allocated by the device runtime it to copy it within a kernel to memory allocated by the host and passed to the running kernel.

The device runtime supports both `memcpy` and `cudaMemcpyAsync` for device to device memory copies. I suspect that those would be your best options in this case. You should study [this section](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#api-reference) of the documentation carefully so that you understand the limitations of the device runtime API.

Comment: I have read that part but wasn't ready to just give up on this idea yet:) I was thinking about using uva and with a header that indicates whether or not the data was manipulated by gpu and cpu keep on scanning that location. Would that be a good idea? If u want me to write the code out i will do it after I am home.

Comment: I think you should provide some more information about the problem you are trying to solve. There are many different strategies that can be used to deal with kernels that output variable amounts of data, you usually do not need device side malloc for that.